# Compiling a recursive function

Tags: recursion, compile

I'm trying to compile a recursive function that spits out the n-th Fibonacci number. I have a working uncompiled function, I just can't seem to get the compiled version working. Here's the code:

```
FibComp = Compile[{k}, f[1] = 1; 
f[2] = 1; 
f[k] = f[k-1] + f[k-2]]
```

When I run it with for example FibComp[29], I get the output

```
f[27] + f[28]
```

and a warning: *Compiled expression f[27.]+f[28.] should be a machine-size real number.*

What am I missing?

Comment: Recursive definitions are currently not compilable.

Comment: @J.M. Interestingly, `FibComp = Compile[{{k, _Integer}}, f[k]]` compiles and returns the correct result (after fixing the definition of `f`) without any warning, but it is slower than the uncompiled version. I haven't worked much with `Compile`, but shouldn't a warning be issued if the uncompiled version is used?

Comment: @Mathe, if you've done that, try ``Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]; CompilePrint[FibComp]``. If you see a `MainEvaluate[]` anywhere in the printout, that part was in fact not compiled.

Comment: You were right, there's a `MainEvaluate[]` in there. But it's nice to know that something like `CompilePrint` exists.